# Removed Mine filter and want to make All be default on Post page

Tags: wordpress

I've  made a function to hide the Mine filter in the screen `wp-admin/edit.php`, using unset:

[image]

But when I click in the Posts menu (`wp-admin/edit.php`), it will not go to **`All`** by default, it still goes to **`Mine`** filter.

How to make the default to be **`All`**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can intercept what page we arrived at the very beginning of the load process (with [`load-(page)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29)) and check if redirection is needed. See comments for logic.

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() 
{
    global $typenow;

    // Not our post type, bail out
    if( 'post' !== $typenow )
        return;

    // Administrator users don't need this, bail out
    if( current_user_can('add_users') )
        return;

    // Only the Mine tab fills this conditions, redirect
    if( !isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) && !isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?all_posts=1') );
        exit();
    }   
});
```